# Wordpress Loop inside Shortcode creates infinite page load (post query)

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, shortcode

So I have looked at every possible solution and read through most similar questions, I just couldn't find the error inside my shortcode for a post query in wordpress.

This is the complete Code:

```
function common_cats(){
    global $posts;
    $parts = array();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $teile = explode("|", $title);

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'tag_slug__in'     => $teile
        );
        
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $output = "<ul>";
        if( $posts->have_posts() ){
            while($posts->have_posts()): $post->the_post();

            $output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">";
            $output .= "<li>".get_the_title(). "<br>";
            $output .= "<img class=\"sbf-background\" src=\"".get_the_post_thumbnail_url()."\"></img>";
            $output .= get_the_excerpt()."</li>"."</a><!--  ends here -->";
            endwhile;
        }
        $output .= "</ul>"; 
        return $output;
}

add_shortcode('commoncats', 'common_cats');
```

Through testing I could boil the problem down to this part of the code:

```
if( $posts->have_posts() ){
            while($posts->have_posts()): $post->the_post();

            $output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">";
            $output .= "<li>".get_the_title(). "<br>";
            $output .= "<img class=\"sbf-background\" src=\"".get_the_post_thumbnail_url()."\"></img>";
            $output .= get_the_excerpt()."</li>"."</a><!--  ends here -->";
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
```

But looking at it I just don't see whats causing my site to break additionally the code will work if I comment out these lines

```
#if( $posts->have_posts() ){
        #   while($posts->have_posts()): $post->the_post();

            $output .= "<a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">";
            $output .= "<li>".get_the_title(). "<br>";
            $output .= "<img class=\"sbf-background\" src=\"".get_the_post_thumbnail_url()."\"></img>";
            $output .= get_the_excerpt()."</li>"."</a><!--  ends here -->";
        #   endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        #}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? `add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');`

Comment: It may or may not help, but the [general recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755) is to avoid `query_posts`. My recommendation is to _always_ use `get_posts unless you have a specific need for something else. You also get to avoid the whole reset post data stuff, too.

Comment: "add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');" is just a useless snippet left from testing some stuff before but unrelated

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I have replaced query_posts